# What's the performance of PyImport_ImportModule(), and what are the best practices for using it?

Tags: python, python-import, cpython, python-c-api

I have an inner loop C function which (in my case) constructs a Python `datetime` object:

```
PyObject* my_inner_loop_fn(void* some_data) {
    PyObject* datetime = PyImport_ImportModule("datetime");
    if (datetime == NULL) return NULL;
    PyObject* datetime_date = PyObject_GetAttrString(datetime, "date");
    PyObject* result = NULL;
    if (datetime_date != NULL) {
        /* long long my_year, my_month, my_day = ... ; */
        PyObject* args = Py_BuildValue("(LLL)", my_year, my_month, my_day);
        res = PyObject_Call(datetime_date, args, NULL);
        Py_XDECREF(args);
    }
    Py_XDECREF(datetime_date);
    Py_DECREF(datetime);
    return result;
}
```

My questions:

- Does the `PyImport_ImportModule("datetime")` reload the entire module from scratch every time, or is it cached?
- If it is not cached:

  - What is the preferred method of caching it?
  - When is the earliest time it is safe to try importing the other module? Can I assign it to a global variable, for example?

I want to avoid paying a heavy cost for the import, since the function runs frequently. Is the above expected to be performant code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the `PyImport_ImportModule("datetime")` reload the entire module from scratch every time, or is it cached?

The standard behaviour is [to first check `sys.modules` to see if the module has already been imported](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-module-cache) and return that if possible. It's only reloaded if it hasn't been imported successfully.

You can obviously test that yourself by putting some code with a visible side-effect in a module and importing that multiple times (e.g. a print statement).

The module import system *is* customizable however, so I believe it's possible for another module to choose to modify that behaviour (as an example, `pyximport` module for example has an option to always reload). Therefore, it's not 100% guaranteed.

It may still be worth caching because there's some cost in doing the look-up - it's a balance between the convenience of not having to cache it yourself and speed.

> When is the earliest time it is safe to try importing the other module?

It's safe after the Python interpreter has been initialized. If you're embedding Python in a C/C++ program this is something you need to think about. If you're writing a Python extension module then you can be confident that the interpreter is initialized for your module to be imported.

> Can I assign it to a global variable, for example?

Yes. However, global variables make it a little difficult for your module to support being unloaded and reloaded cleanly. Lots of C extensions choose not to worry about this. However, the [`PyModule_GetState`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/module.html#c.PyModule_GetState) mechanism is designed to support this use-case so you might choose to put your cache in the extension module state.